# How can I move data from one field to another, then make the original field blank?

Tags: visual-workflow, custom

I created a custom object that allows managers to input PTO marking the employee as out and unavailable for calls.  Now they are requesting for 2 more PTO date options, with the data moving to new fields and making the previous one blank.  I have been able to make the data transfer from PTO 1 to PTO 2, but it doesn't clear PTO 2, just duplicates the data.  Is this a possibility at all?  Here's the flow I used to attempt this.  Any suggestions would be appreciated![image: Flow Update Records field]

Answer (score 1):

Assignments are not moves, they are copies. All you need to do is to assign the `$Global.NullValue` variable to the field you wish to clear out.

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense!